# Обратиться к слоту

Tags: c++, qt

Расширяю класс, создаю таймер и слот таймера. При исполнении говорит, что нет слота в классе, который расширяю. Как подписаться на слот, который в расширяемом классе?

```
    Graph::Graph(QWidget *parent) : QCustomPlot(parent)
    {
      ...
        trackTimer = new QTimer(); 
        connect(trackTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(PlaybackStep()));
        qDebug() << this->metaObject()->className(); // выдаёт QCustomPlot а нужно Graph
        trackTimer->start(100);
    }
    void Graph::PlaybackStep()
    {...}
```

Вывод приложения `QObject::connect: No such slot QCustomPlot::PlaybackStep() in ..\stms2\src\graph.cpp:21`
Спасибо.

Comment: Как Вы объявляете слот? Приведите кусок кода, включая секцию. Возможно, что не записали её как, например, `public slots`. Для уже устаревшего синтаксиса подключения сигналов к слотам этот момент принципиален.

Comment: Также, возможно, забыт `Q_OBJECT` в объявлении класса.

Comment: Добавьте еще в вопрос сообщение об ошибке. Кстати, если используется *Qt5*, то можно проверку корректности вызова `connect` перенести на этап компиляции.

Comment: @alexis031182 по сути вы уже дали ответ на вопрос в комментарии. Я этого не заметил. Если вы хотите дать свой ответ я удалю свой, так, наверное, будет справедливо

Comment: @asianirish, нет-нет, всё в порядке. Дополните, может быть, только объявлением слота через тот же `public slots`.

Comment: @alexis031182 OK дополнил

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Объявите Q_OBJECT в классе Graph. Примерно так:

```
class Graph : public QCustomPlot
{
Q_OBJECT //Добавить это
public:
...
public slots: //есть вероятность, что вы забыли public slots (либо private slots, protected slots)
    void PlaybackStep(); //Ваш слот
};
```

Перед компиляцией кликните правой кнопкой мыши по узлу проекта и выберите **"Run qmake"** чтобы не заглючило.